# Which is faster/better: always update table vs hashing and check before update

Tags: php, mysql, hash

I am creating a webpage with supporting editor. Whenever user change content in editor, I send this data to server using ajax. Normally, server will update database to store data. However, I think that it is not good for performance because it takes time to process update query continuously.

Instead that, I have an idea. I will hash content (md5 alg) and save code in same table. When new content comes, I hash it and compare with old code. If they is not equal, I will do update.

However, I am not sure this idea is good because md5 also takes time to do ([~7 seconds for 1 MB](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php)). Can you give me some advice?

Comment: md5 is generally considered a fast hashing algorithm (that's one of its major failings for passwords, the second being too many clashes) but a crc32 will be faster than md5... but if you choose the hashing approach, save the hash alongside the last saved data, so you don't constantly have to recalculate the hash

Comment: In PHP hash page, somebody run testing for crc32 alg with ~7.5 seconds. So I think md5 is faster than crc32.

Comment: Theoretically, crc32 should be faster..... but the best way to find out is to try for yourself.... just because somebody else reports crc test of 7.5 seconds for a test on their machine, and your md5 test is 7 seconds on your machine, doesn't mean that crc32 is slower.... either way save the hash or checksum value alongside the last saved data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save latest content in session. Then if new ajax data is same as one saved in session then you don't do db update, otherwise you do. It will be much faster than md5 or multiple update queries.

Code should be something like:

```
$new_data = $_POST['editor_text'];
if(!isset($_SESSION['editor_text']) || $_SESSION['editor_text'] != $new_data){
   $db->update($new_data);
   $_SESSION['editor_text'] = $new_data;
}
```

Above should do it, if your application is used by small number of people. If by luck you go big (1000+ concurrent users of editor), configure memcache on your server and allocate it decent RAM and instead of saving text in session, save it in memcache.. it will boost your performance.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. But comparing string is faster hashing, isn't it?

Comment: Just slightly faster, but considering that you will have to  fetch md5 from table, session idea helps you avoid any roundtrip to database.